# After Uglify TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I made a proyect with typescript (3.9.3) and Node (10.16.3) code but now I want to uglify the code, parsing it to javascript and executing uglifyJS. So when I did this proccess the services that work before are not working now. I has been debugging the code and I know that the problem is when the process executes this line, most concretly when it try to load express.

`var v, m, g = require("fs"), y = e(require("path")), w = e(require("cors")), C = e(require("express")), x = e(require("body-parser"))`

The error is the following

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Someone knows what is happening here?
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

After a few probes with tsc I solved the problem.
Caution with typescript imports sometimes in transpilation process could be a huge headhache if package.json and tsconfig.json has configuration with incorrect parameters